# texmode in emacs and \typein

Tags: latex3, emacs

I use emacs to compose my latex source code, under the texmode.  The file I'm working requires inputs from the user:

```
   \typein[\answer]{Enter info here:  }
```

Everytime I process this file within emacs, I got the error message

```
   Enter info here:  

   ! Emergency stop.
   <read 0> 

   l.6 \typein[\answer]{Enter info here:}
                                      ^^M
   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I process the file in a terminal, then it works and I get no error message.  How should I tweak my emacs and/or tex setup so I can process this file with \typein within emacs?  THANKS!

Comment: A comment, because I haven't looked fully into it, but the emacs 'TeX mode' compile runs in non-stop mode. I'll see if I can find the way to change it (unless someone else beats me to it by knowing already)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have now checked how to do this in Emacs (this is for GNU Emacs version 26.1, but should not really be different in other versions).

Assuming that you are using the graphical version (and not the text only version), use the `Options` menu, and select the `Customize Emacs` sub-menu. On that, select `Specific Group...`. There will be a request for information in the mini-buffer, asking which group to customize. Type `tex-run` as the answer. Scroll to the setting for `Tex Start Commands`, and expand it. There should be a set of radio buttons, with `Nonstop ("\nonstopmode\input")` selected. Select `Interactive (nil)` and set for current session (or save for future sessions, if you prefer).

Of course, being Emacs, there is almost certainly a way to set it without mucking about with the menus, by doing something in your `.emacs` file (or `init.el`, or similar, depending on version), and `Save for future sessions` will adjust that file anyway. If you want specific help with that method, you will need to ask at [emacs.se](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/), not here. The variable you will need to change, in that case, is `tex-start-commands`.

Next time you TeX-Compile (`C-c C-f`, or any other shortcut you have defined), it will run in interactive mode. Note that this means it will stop and ask for your help if there is a problem with your document. It will, however, also ask for your input when using `\typein`.